# Getting error message while initializing IBM MQ from java class

Tags: ibm-mq

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mqjbnd05 in java.library.path

while creating a MQQueueManager.

I have no idea why this is happening.. Can u please help me.

Comment: The error itself answering the question that `no mqjbnd05 in java.library.path`. So please add it and then re-try :)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Arun,Actually I cant find any this kind of file.. can you please tell me from where i can get this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth noting that the mqjbnd05 is a the library that was loaded by the MQ v6 Java clients. 
MQ v6 is now out of support.

mqjbnd is the name of the library from v7 onwards.

Comment: :: Thanx for uor reply.. problem solved..i was a configuration error..i was not configuring the mq correctly.. and thanks for the info about the out of support..

Answer (score 2):

The error means the MQ client has attempted to load the mqjbnd library but can not find it on the java.library path provided. The MQ client tried to load that library as the application has specified a transport type of 'bindings' which means that the MQ client application will exist on the same physically machine as the MQ server, and so a bindings connection (not TCP/IP) will be made.

So resolve the issue you need to find out if your java application should exist on the same physically machine as the MQ Server (QueueManager) that you want to connect to. If it should be then the mqjbnd library (.dll or .so) should be located in the java/lib directory. Add this to the java.library (PATH on windows or LD_LIBRARY_PATH on unix).

If your application is to be remote to the MQ Server then you must change your java code to use a transport type of 'client'. There is no need to reference any libraries when connecting remotely.

Comment: Thanks @whitefiea... This thing solved but it was regarding the host error.. i mean i was giving a wrong host name,so thats why i guess it was failing to connect. Not sure if it is the only reason.